# Thingsboard widget development : how to store daily telemetry of a device in an array?

Tags: javascript, widget, thingsboard, telemetry

I am working on Thingsboard widget developement. I would like to export the telemetry data of one of my devices to be stored in some kind of array. I want to store like the daily telemetry data in this array. How can I manage this storage while choosing which lapse of time I'm storing the data from in JavaScript?

Thank you so much!